# Setting up routing in ASP.net web API for Angular frontend

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to set up my current Web API to serve an Angular 6 frontend application.

My Angular project is located in 'app' directory under the Web API.

I can navigate to the base page fine and all the frontend routing works fine.

My development is on:
https://test2.localhost.com/app/

I did have to set the base location in index.html to *base href="/app/"*.

Now my issue comes to direct navigation to sub urls of app. For example :

https://test2.localhost.com/app/information/planets

I get a 404 which leads me to believe the issue lies within the Web API routing.

If i was to start the angular app at https://test2.localhost.com/app/ i can navigate to the url, but not from a cold start in the browser.

I have tried several rewrite rules within the web.config but all seems to fail and stops me from navigate to the https://test2.localhost.com/app

The Web API is running on IIS.

When running the frontend on Node.Js the routing works fine and I can navigate to all sub urls from a cold start.

Comment: Just run the app in Node.js then. Separating the frontend and backend is perfectly fine

Comment: I accept that its perfectly fine to separate the frontend and backend, but manageability is key having it in one application/deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you also have MVC routes, try this for your route.config:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new
            {
                // Add all routes we need MVC to handle here
                serverRoute = new ServerRouteConstraint(url =>
                {
                    return url.PathAndQuery.StartsWith("/qbo",
                        StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                })
            });

        // This is a catch-all for when no other routes matched. Let the Angular 2+ router take care of it
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "angular",
            url: "{*url}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // The view that bootstraps Angular 2+
        );
    }
```

Here's the route constraint class:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Web
{
public class ServerRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private readonly Func<Uri, bool> _predicate;

    public ServerRouteConstraint(Func<Uri, bool> predicate)
    {
        this._predicate = predicate;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName,
        RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return this._predicate(httpContext.Request.Url);
    }
}
}
```

I've been using this for a long time, not sure which blog I may have been inspired by.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, not sure if its the best way but it works.

I created a controller called FEController (FrontEndController).

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return File(Server.MapPath("/app/") + "index.html", "text/html");
}
```

Then added a map route in the RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Angular",
   "{app}/{*pathInfo}",
   new { controller = "FE", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "HelpMain", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Tested and confirmed working.